# Spring @Transactional(Propgation.nested) Generic Example

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

can any body provide some insight here..

I have been having hard time, while getting through spring @Transactional(Propagation Nested)

I have been searching all over internet and here, but unable to find any generic example of specific type regarding this..

```
mtdOne(User userObj1, User userObj2)
{
someBean.mtdtwo( userObj1);
someBean.mtdThree(userObj2);

}


mtdTwo(userObj1)
 {
//calling dao and insert data into DATABASE
daoObj.save(userObj1);
}

mtdThree(userObj2)
 {
//calling dao second time and insert data into DATABASE
daoObj.save(userObj2);
}
```

so, in this case, where so many database interactions are happening, i want to implement *TRANSACTIONAL(PROPAGATION.NESTED)* and **examine its behavior and practically see how it is working..**

so, if any body has better generic case and if they discuss it here, it is most welcome..

any suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want mtdTwo and mtdThree to use the same transaction i.e. if one of them rolls back the other does too and they are committed together(and some more togetherness features); you should use `REQUIRED` propagation instead. In that case, your code would look something like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
mtdOne(User userObj1, User userObj2)
{
someBean.mtdtwo( userObj1);
someBean.mtdThree(userObj2);

}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
mtdTwo(userObj1)
 {
//calling dao and insert data into DATABASE
daoObj.save(userObj1);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
mtdThree(userObj2)
 {
//calling dao second time and insert data into DATABASE
daoObj.save(userObj2);
}
```

With the above code, the transaction would start at `mtdone` and the same transaction will be used by `mtdTwo` and `mtdThree`.

`Propagation.NESTED` in spring is a way to implement save points so that one can have the flexibility of save points within one transaction. For more details about the different propagation supported by Spring; take a look at this: [Propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

One example for NESTED can be:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   mtdOne(List<User> userObjList, User userObj2)
   {
      for(User userObj1 : userObjList) {
          someBean.mtdtwo(userObj1);
       }
        someBean.mtdThree(userObj2);
   }

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED)
mtdTwo(userObj1)
 {
     //calling dao and insert data into DATABASE
        daoObj.save(userObj1);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
mtdThree(userObj2) {
  //calling dao second time and insert data into DATABASE
  daoObj.save(userObj2);
}
```

With this code, even if one of the userobj1 fails to be processed because of some database related error (unique constaint, etc); the transaction would be rolled back to the last savepoint(when the previous userObj1 in the list was processed) and will process the next userobj1 in the list if present and then move on to mthdtwo instead of rolling back the whole transaction back till mtdOne

Comment: actually i am interested in knowing how TRAN NESTED works... but there is no example found anywhere...

Comment: could you provide a generic example for spring tran nested.. and if you suggest any changes to question so tht it should reflect a generic example of TRAN NESTED, i will make those changes and repost it... thankyou..

Comment: Edited my answer with that info